# Numerically solving ODEs that can't be expressed explicitly

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm an engineer and therefore not as knowledgeable most of you, so please don't lynch me if I ask something stupid.

How can we efficiently solve a nth order ODE which can not directly be expressed as a function of its highest derivative. E.g:

\begin{equation}
 \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} - x = \sin\left(\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\right) - \frac{df}{dx} - \ln\left(2\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\right)
\end{equation}

If I could solve it for the highest deriavtive I could easily reduce the ODE into two first order ODEs and use a single-step-method. I've already searched for solutions but as I have a hard time correctly expressing my problem, I haven't found anything useful.

If I misuse the term explicit and implicit in this context, please enlighten me how to say it right.

Comment: What are initial or boundary  conditions? without them it is impossible to calculate numerically.

Comment: This was more of a general question regarding the problem described and not for the specific ODE shown. In my case these problems are amlost always nonlinear second order ODEs with either inital or boundary conditions. ICs / BCs are always real numbers. What would be the general strategy for such problems? Can they be transformed so that I can use single-step solvers like RK45?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the order of the ODE by differentiation. Then in
$$
f'''(x)-1=\cos(f''(x))f'''(x)-f''(x)-\frac{f'''(x)}{f''(x)}
$$
one can easily isolate $f'''(x)$. The non-linear equation only needs to be solved once to enhance the initial state with the second derivative.

Comment: Haven't expected that the answer would be so trivial, but it seems this will work in pretty much every case. Thank you for you answer